# Tasklist csv script

Tags: windows, batch-file, tasklist

I'm trying to create a log file that include process and memory consumption on a windows desktop.
I'm new to script programming and i'm really struggling to complete this task.
I found that command tasklist returns pretty much all the information i need. However i would like to make a script that `runs tasklist /fo csv >> c:\processes.csv` 
every 5 minutes... My main problem is how to include a column with date and time when the command was executed on the csv output file.

default csv file is:

"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage"

i would like

"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage", "datetime"

I didn't find a way to customize the columns on the tasklist /fo csv.

Can anyone help me? Sorry for the bad english... it isn't my main language.

Comment: Try `timeout /?`, `help goto` and `help call`. Another option is to setup a task to run every 5 minutes in Task Scheduler. The command line would then be `tasklist /fo csv >> c:\processes.csv`, no need to invoke cmd.exe.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. SO is not a coding service.  You have to make an attempt at researching the problem, show us what you've tried and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: i'm stuck on how to include a column with timestamp ( date and time) with the exacty moment i collected the running process on the output csv file. I didn't find a way to customize the columns on the tasklist /fo csv. Any thoughts? Thanks for help.

Comment: And yet, you've demonstrated no effort at all. [Edit] your post, add an MCVE.

Comment: I'll try to improve for the next questions. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to process the output of your command and simply add your desired string.

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /fo csv') do echo %%a, %date% %time%)>>c:\processes.csv
```

To execute it all five minutes, put a loop around like:

```
:loop
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /fo csv') do echo %%a, %date%)>>c:\processes.csv
timeout 300
goto :loop
```

or better (if you want to run it all day long in the background) add it as a scheduled task (of course without the loop) to run every five minutes.

Comment: @ViníciusCrisântemodeJesus, you're expected to mark the answer as accepted, if you find it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The `FOR` command with the `/F` option will allow you to capture the output of a command. You can then add the date and time to each line of output.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('tasklist /fo csv') DO ECHO %date% %time%,%%G>>process.csv
```